# Record audio + AirPlay

Tags: iphone, ios, record, audiounit, airplay

I'm making an app that allows you to do this: speaking and while you speak it share what you said to the AppleTV using AirPlay. The problem is that to record audio I use AVAudioRecorder and I pick the recorded audio from a path, which doesn't update the file length while I'm talking. Then, I thought I should use I/O Remote Audio Units to record and save to a path, but I'm not able to do so. Is there anyone who could help me whit this ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to do it your self here is a [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/UsingSpecificAudioUnits/UsingSpecificAudioUnits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH17-SW1) ... if you have some question fell free to ask